# Targeted architecture of .NET assembly using Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, mono.cecil, bit-depth

Can I find whether a .NET assembly has been specifically build for 32 or 64 bits using Mono.Cecil? Or any other way of finding out without having to load the assembly first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mono-ceci, you can do this (the information is available module by module):

```
AssemblyDefinition asm = AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly("myassembly.dll");

foreach (ModuleDefinition module in asm.Modules)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Module " + module.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("IsPE64 " + module.Image.PEOptionalHeader.StandardFields.IsPE64);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Was I supposed to be able to find this without asking online? Cecil code isn't commented and I couldn't find a good resource that explains the terminology and concepts involved.

Comment: @DavidRutten - that's very true. I found it digging in the source in fact (and I know what I was looking for, the Image part).

Answer (score 2):

`moduleDefinition.Architecture` is of type `TargetArchitecture` witch is defined as:

```
public enum TargetArchitecture {
    I386,
    AMD64,
    IA64,
    ARMv7,
}
```

There is another property, `moduleDefinition.Attributes` of type `ModuleAttributes`:

```
[Flags]
public enum ModuleAttributes {
    ILOnly = 1,
    Required32Bit = 2,
    StrongNameSigned = 8,
    Preferred32Bit = 0x00020000,
}
```